# JavaScript/Iframe in static FBML

Tags: facebook, fbml, facebook-fbml, staticfbml

Is there any way the following script can be embedded in static [FBML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Facebook_Markup_Language)?

```
<script src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>

<script>
    new TWTR.Widget({
        version: 2,
        type: 'profile',
        rpp: 4,
        interval: 6000,
        width: 250,
        height: 300,
        theme: {
            shell: {
                background: '#333333',
                color: '#ffffff'
            },
            tweets: {
                background: '#000000',
                color: '#ffffff',
                links: '#4aed05'
            }
        },
        features: {
            scrollbar: false,
            loop: false,
            live: false,
            hashtags: true,
            timestamp: true,
            avatars: false,
            behavior: 'all'
        }
    }).render().setUser('twitter').start();
</script>
```

I have tried following code in the static FBML, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<fb:iframe
    scrolling='no'
    frameborder='0'
    marginheight='0'
    src='http://www.demo.kaazunut.com/twitter-box.html'
    height='500'
    width='500'></fb:iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have this in a separate page, and load an iFrame page within your FBML canvas.

Here's how to call an iFrame page inside an FBML canvas page:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/iframe/

-Roozbeh

Comment: Hello @Roozbeh15, please check iframe code I added (added to the problem description)